# How to change parent view property from child view in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want to change parent view property(which binds to UI control) from the child view model.How to do it?
Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Gowtham

Comment: Events work nice for this or you can create a Static action method in the Parent view.  Or if you want to get real technical about it, you can create a message bus.

Comment: I use in such cases one of two approaches: 1) fire event in child view-model and subscribe to this event in parent vm 2) create an interface with desired methods, implement it in parent vm and pass reference on parent vm to child vm by this interface. If nesting level is greater than 1 I prefer the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

A child view model has no knowledge about the parent by default. You could either inject the child with a reference to the parent when you create it, e.g.

```
public MethodInParent()
{
    var child = new ChildViewModel(this);
}
```

Or you could use a messenger or an event aggregator to send messages or events between the child and the parent in a loosely coupled way. Please refer to the following link for more information about this concept: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/.

Comment: Note that `ChildViewModel` should not take entire parent view model as an argument since it is a bad practice. Child view model have to know about parent one only what it needs and nothing more. Constructor of the `ChildViewModel` can take some interface implemented in the parent view model.